# Keep getting Null on String with Random

Tags: java, null

it's Java Starter here, so i was Coding my program which makes a Password, i used the Random Object to have a random Number that will choose what Letter comes or What number comes.

I keep getting the Numbers and the Symbols Only.. what i get is something Like this:

"9=9null=99" I don't understand Why there's a null. Java doesn't show me any problems with my code (Doesn't show Null Pointer exception.)

Here's My code:

```
    package project.Secureword.com;
import java.awt.*;



import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Main {

    private static JFrame start;
    private static TextField field;
    private static String password;
    private static String lastpass;
    public static Settings passsettings;

    public static Random r;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        passsettings = new Settings();
        passsettings.setIfDots(true);
        passsettings.setIfLowercase(true);
        passsettings.setIfNum(true);
        passsettings.setIfUpprcase(true);
        Settings.changerun();
        start();
    }

    public static void start() {
        Font a = new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 0);
        Font size = a.deriveFont(20f);
        JButton createPass = new JButton();
        createPass.setText("<html> Click me to <br> Generate a Password! <html>");
        createPass.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        JLabel text = new JLabel();
        text.setText("<html> Welcome to SECUREPASS! <br> An Extreme Strong Password Generator <br> Developed by OfficialCode");
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
        text.setFont(size);




        field = new TextField(20);
        field.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));





        start = new JFrame("Secureword | Strong password Generator | Coded by OfficialCode");
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(390,390));
        start.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        start.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        start.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        start.getContentPane().add(createPass, BorderLayout.WEST);
        start.getContentPane().add(text, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        start.getContentPane().add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        start.pack();
        start.setVisible(true);
        password = "";


        createPass.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                field.setText(null);
                field.selectAll();
                allrandom();

            }});



}
    public static void allrandom() {
        String[] pass = new String[8];
        Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < pass.length ; i++) {
        int ch = 0;
        ch = r.nextInt(3);
        switch(ch) {
        case 1:
            if(passsettings.isIfDots()) {
                String newchar = ""; 
                newchar = dotpass();
                pass[i] = newchar;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            if(passsettings.isIfNum()) {
                String newchar2 = ""; 
                newchar2 = Numpass();
                pass[i] = newchar2;
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            String newchar3 = ""; 
            newchar3 = charchose();
            pass[i] = newchar3;
            break;
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < pass.length ; i++) {
        String newpasschar = "";
        newpasschar = pass[i];
        password = password + newpasschar;
    }
    field.setText(password);

        // random() end
    }

    public static String uppercasepass() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN3 = 0;
        rN3 = r.nextInt(26);
        switch(rN3) {
        case 1:
            passletter = "A";
        case 2:
            passletter = "B";
        case 3:
            passletter = "C";
        case 4:
            passletter = "D";
        case 5:
            passletter = "E";
        case 6:
            passletter = "F";
        case 7:
            passletter = "G";
        case 8:
            passletter = "H";
        case 9:
            passletter = "I";
        case 10:
            passletter = "J";
        case 11:
            passletter = "K";
        case 12:
            passletter = "L";
        case 13:
            passletter = "M";
        case 14:
            passletter = "N";
        case 15:
            passletter = "O";
        case 16:
            passletter = "P";
        case 17:
            passletter = "Q";
        case 18:
            passletter = "R";
        case 19:
            passletter = "S";
        case 20:
            passletter = "T";
        case 21:
            passletter = "U";
        case 22:
            passletter = "V";
        case 23:
            passletter = "W";
        case 24:
            passletter = "X";
        case 25:
            passletter = "Y";
        case 26:
            passletter = "Z";


    }

        return passletter;
    // uppercase() end
}

    public static String lowercasepass() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN3 = 0;
        rN3 = r.nextInt(26);
        switch(rN3) {
        case 1:
            passletter = "a";
        case 2:
            passletter = "b";
        case 3:
            passletter = "c";
        case 4:
            passletter = "d";
        case 5:
            passletter = "e";
        case 6:
            passletter = "f";
        case 7:
            passletter = "g";
        case 8:
            passletter = "h";
        case 9:
            passletter = "i";
        case 10:
            passletter = "j";
        case 11:
            passletter = "k";
        case 12:
            passletter = "l";
        case 13:
            passletter = "m";
        case 14:
            passletter = "n";
        case 15:
            passletter = "o";
        case 16:
            passletter = "p";
        case 17:
            passletter = "q";
        case 18:
            passletter = "r";
        case 19:
            passletter = "s";
        case 20:
            passletter = "t";
        case 21:
            passletter = "u";
        case 22:
            passletter = "v";
        case 23:
            passletter = "w";
        case 24:
            passletter = "x";
        case 25:
            passletter = "y";
        case 26:
            passletter = "z";


    }

        return passletter;
    }

    public static String Numpass() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN = 0;
        rN = r.nextInt(9);
        switch(rN) {
        case 1:
            passletter = "1";
        case 2:
            passletter = "2";
        case 3:
            passletter = "3";
        case 4:
            passletter = "4";
        case 5:
            passletter = "5";
        case 6:
            passletter = "6";
        case 7:
            passletter = "7";
        case 8:
            passletter = "8";
        case 9:
            passletter = "9";
        }
        return passletter;
    }

    public static String dotpass() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String passletter = "";
        int rN5 = 0;
        rN5 = r.nextInt(5);
        switch(rN5) {
        case 1:
            passletter = "_";
        case 2:
            passletter = "]";
        case 3:
            passletter = "$";
        case 4:
            passletter = "#";
        case 5:
            passletter = "=";


        }




        return passletter;
    }


    public static String charchose() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String line = "";
        int rN = 0;
        rN = r.nextInt(20);
        switch(rN) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
            if(passsettings.isIfLowercase()) {
                line = lowercasepass();
            }
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:
        case 16:
        case 17:
        case 18:
        case 19:
        case 20:
            if(passsettings.isIfUpprcase()) {
                line = uppercasepass();
            }

        }






        return line;
    }





}
```

Comment: Off topic : The `String` class in Java does have `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` methods.

Comment: `rN` will never be 9, but it *can* be 0 (which you don't have a `case` for).

Comment: `nextInt(26)` returns `int` values in the range 0-25, not 1-26 .

Comment: String[] alphabet = ... ; pass = alphabet[rN]; -> an approach like this would decrease your line count with dozens, and make it a lot easier to read/debug

Comment: and you just have to add `'a'` to your random value to have the same result. `r.nextInt(26) + 'a'`. **By the way, you never `break` your switch** ! Explaining you only have `9` and `=`. But can't find the `null` reason, too many lines.

Comment: Well, yes, same reason than `nextInt(26)` output a range 0-25, `nextInt(3)` return a range of 0-2, so your first switch (symbol, number or letter) don't do anything for `0`, letting the `pass[i] = null`

Comment: Stultske You're soultion fixed my problem. Thanks for the help. and now i actually notcied that i forgot that's java starts to count from 0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that `Random.nextInt(n)` return a value between 0-n (exclusive). Your switch case are all wrong by one.

This explain your null since you don't do anything for `ch = 0`, the `String` stays at `null`:

```
switch(ch){
case 1: ... //symbol
case 2 ... //number
case 3: ... //letter
}
```

This should be

```
switch(ch){
case 0: ... //symbol
case 1: ... //number
case 2: ... //letter
}
```

Some other issues or improvments :

- You don't `break` after a `case` so you always get the last case executed (well all following case). Resulting in a possibilities of 4 character `zZ9=` (easy to bruteforce !)
- You should use a `char[]` instead of `String[]`, there is no need of using `String` to store one character like you do.

Instead of

```
String s = "a";
```

you can

```
char c = 'a';
```

Reducing the length of the code if you read the next point.

- You can reduce your switch by doing some addition like `'a' + r.nextInt(26)` to get a value between `'a'` to `'z'`
- For a random symbol, instead of a switch, create a static array of `char[]` with every character, then get a random value using the size of this array.

Like :

```
 final static char[] symbol = {'#', '@', '-', '\\', '/', '*'};

 static getRadomSymbol(){
     Random r = new Random();
     return symbol[r.nextInt(symbol.length)];
 }
```

Allowing the add of character easily (and reducing again the number of line ;) )

Comment: _You should use a `char[]` instead of `String[]`_ Both are not the same, did you mean `String` or `char[][]`?

Comment: @Nathan Check OP's code to get what is is the `String[]` usage, he stores one character per cell using his `String` representation. Yes those are not the same, but in this case, building a `String`, a `char[]` is enough to get any UNICODE value. EDIT : edited to be a bit more complet (but this seems confusing now)

Comment: Oh. well. i didn't refresh the page so i couldn't saw Your solution anyways i found a better and much "cleaner" way to fix my problem. Thanks for the solution anyways

Comment: @AxelH Sure, Stulltsuke commented that on the question That's basically the way:

Comment: @AxelH `String[] abc = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};` And`passletter = abc[rN3];`

Comment: @JavaStarter indeed ... `char passletter = (char)(rN3 + 'A'):`, same for lowercase  `passletter = (char)(rN3 + 'a'):`.